# "do-release-upgrade -d" doesn't prompt for update

Tags: server, upgrade, release-management

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server and I would like to place that PC for testing purposes so moving to 12.10 server but I am unable to do that. I am doing this in a VM, so I can't copy/paste the text report. I took a screenshot instead.

I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` maybe prompt value is lts where it should be normal

Comment: Yeah this was my issue. Changed `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` and it's upgrading like a charm.

Comment: Yeah its seems like to be . right now I'm not with pc . I'll try and let you know later

Comment: Sorry for late , I am just busy with usual works .

Answer (score 0):

Could whatever mirror your packages get update from (in `/etc/apt/sources.list`) not contain the current beta release? You could try using a different mirror.

Comment: i think its main server , because i havent changed it after install